# EventListener show hide on hover

Tags: javascript, css, events, hover, mouseover

I have a button with CSS-class and -ID **openproduktkat** in my header. If I hover the button, an object with CSS-class and -ID **menuproduktkat** should open. If I leave the button or the objective, the objective should close. There should be a delay between leaving the objective with my mouse before it will be closed.
Can someone help me with this problem? I'm a beginner in coding and this seems to me pretty difficult ...

That's what I tried:

```
var openproduktkat = document.getElementById('openproduktkat');
var menuproduktkat = document.getElementById('menuproduktkat');
openproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
openproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);
function mouseOver() {
menuproduktkat.style = 'display: block;'}
function mouseOut() {
menuproduktkat.style = 'display: none'}
```

Opening and closing by hover **openproduktkat** works, but I don't know how to add a delay and the same hover effect for **menuproduktkat**.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I added it to the question part ...

Comment: Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for timing and [cssText[(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) for setting the styles.

Answer (score 1):

The `mouseOut` function below uses `setTimeout` to delay the hiding by 1 second.

Note that since, as requested, the code would hide the target element after mousing away from the button to the target element, the target element will disappear.

That's probably not the behavior you are looking for, as if the user mouses from the button to the target element, it's most likely that the user expects the target element to stay visible.

Therefore, this code below will cancel the target element hide whenever the user mouses over the element.

```js
const openproduktkat = document.getElementById('openproduktkat');
const menuproduktkat = document.getElementById('menuproduktkat');

let timeoutId = null;

// make target element visible
function mouseOver() {
  menuproduktkat.style.display = "";
  
  // cancel time-delayed hide if it exists
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  }
}

// hide target element after 1 second
function mouseOut(evt) {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    menuproduktkat.style.display = 'none';
    timeoutId = null;
  }, 1000);
}


openproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
openproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);

menuproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
menuproduktkat.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);
```

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="openproduktkat">#openproduktkat</button>
<div id="menuproduktkat" style="display:none">#menuproduktkat</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with setTimeout:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var menuproduktkat = document.getElementById('menuproduktkat');

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {  
    menuproduktkat.style = 'display: block'
})

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        menuproduktkat.style = 'display: none'
    }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Hover!</button>

<div id="menuproduktkat" style="display: none">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: note that OP also needs help with styling from js

Comment: That's still wrong, either use `style.display = 'block'` or `style.cssText = 'display: block;'`